# Too many characters in character literal - trying to check if my value is not within ASCII values '&#092;&#048;'

Tags: java, char

```
/*Visit only nodes with keys*/
    if(root.alpha != '&#092;&#048;'){

    }
```

as the title above says. How would I do this better? I'm trying to check if the character (root.alpha) is not within that spectrum. Thanks.

Comment: What does "within" mean here... Between 0x30 and 0x5C? Or just those two characters?

Comment: You are confusing several things here. 1) A character literal (something between single quotes) can only contain one character. 2) You can only express characters with &x## notation in HTML, not in Java.

Comment: @JimGarrison between characters #092 and #048 on the ascii table.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt oh yeah true, would I use " " instead? And also, how would I do it instead? Sorry, I read it somewhere whilst researching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check that the character is not within the range of the hexadecimal ASCII codes 48 and 92:

```
if (root.alpha < 0x48 || root.alpha > 0x92) {
    // ...
}
```

That is, not within range = less than the start or greater than the end.

Comment: Oh okay. I was confused about how to represent the ascii characters before. Thanks heaps man!

Answer (score 21):

An unrelated mistake on my part that led me here, but I forgot that `'` and `"` aren't interchangeable in Java like they are in some other languages. `'` is for character literals and `"` is for string literals.

So enclosing any sequence longer than one character in `'` will lead to this compile-time error.